# Using pattern search in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

Is it possible to use following pattern in the Query to get the below results?

1.To get all the employee details where Employee number is 8 digits with starting letter as K and rest as integers

Eg: K1234567

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE EMP_NO LIKE '[K\d{7}]'
```

PS: I did not get the desired result by running the query, please suggest if there is anything wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible with the pattern below

```
SELECT *
FROM   EMPLOYEE
WHERE  EMP_NO LIKE 'K' + REPLICATE('[0-9]',7)
```